# Text frame not filling up in indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, book

Hi friends today i have a problem with an indesign book i'm designing: the text that flow into some pages do not fill up page text frames completely.

I don't know if the issue is from my formatting or other options.

I have tried several text frame and character formatting option to no avail.

In the screen shot you can see that the text frame completes all the lines on one page while on the next page (the right hand side) there's a blank line at the bottom and there's no line break.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Could be a number of reasons behind this: keep options, text box height, leading, baseline grid settings or a combination of these. Hard to tell by just looking at the image.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be "Keep options" > Keep 2 lines together at the end/start of paragraph.

Now, you may ask yourself if you prefer to have an empty space as described or end up with [widows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widows_and_orphans)... (I prefer empty spaces, but that's your call)

By the way, you should [avoid adding extra returns](https://indesignsecrets.com/remove-multiple-returns-and-replace-with-space-between-paragraphs.php):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Paragraph style options > Indents and spacing > Uncheck "Balance ragged lines"

Answer (score -3):

It is your text box settings. Go to Object>Text Frame Options (or command B) and select justify. That will spread your text to fill the whole page.

Comment: While this may work.. it's a pretty bad workflow.

Comment: Moreover, it almost certainly _won’t_ work, since the text looks like it’s aligned to the baseline grid and can’t be justified.